# Landing Page Redirect based on Web or Mobile Client

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I am an email developer on the Salesforce Marketing Cloud platform. Is it possible to redirect a person who receives and email to get redirected to a mobile optimized page if opening in a mobile device or web page if opening in a desktop client using ampscript?

Any guidance would be appreciated!